# WordPress Name, Email Id, Age Alert Box

Tags: php, html, mysql, wordpress

Recently we have developed website and deployed it successfully. Now we want to integrate Alert Box which demand User Name, Email Id,Age, Education Qualification when user visit our website first time.

And information must be store in MySQL database, how can we do it? We want to popup this alert box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it to do using Javascript then follow below:

In html page add this in body part

```
<body onload="popup('popup.php','ab')">
```

Then add this Javascript function before closing head tag i.e

```
            <script type="text/javascript">
            function popup(mylink, windowname) { 
            if (! window.focus)
            return true;
             var href; 
             if (typeof(mylink) == 'string') 
             href=mylink; 
             else 
             href=mylink.href; 
             window.open(href, windowname, 'width=400,height=200,scrollbars=yes');
            return false;
            }
            </script>
```

Note: you have to create popup.php page on the same directory as this code and write code to insert into database.